# sdkman is missing less-R command on nixos

Tags: nixos

I recently installed sdkman.io on nixos and came accross some strange errors. After also installing which, jdk, and less I am still getting this error when running `sdk list`

```
less -R: command not found
```

But I am able to run `less` from the same terminal. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assure there is an unescaped space character between `less` and its arguments.

From the error message you can see that shell treated whole string `less -R` as a command, hence the space character in your command execution string is escaped. Likely because somewhere quotes were used (less likely with backslash).

Having a look at sdkman-cli source code, it seems very likely you have `export PAGER="less -R"` in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

In such case line 33 or 35 of [`src/main/bash/sdkman-utils.sh`](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/blob/master/src/main/bash/sdkman-utils.sh) will generate this very error. It seems to be expected as `PAGER` environment variable is used to define executable file and it is assumed it does not contain other options (looks like a common practice rather than standard).

To set up options for `less` an environment variable `LESS` [shall be used](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less), hence in your case the following settings shall be applied:

```
export PAGER=less
export LESS="-R"
```

---

As an exercise you can verify you get this error message on any system by typing the following in shell:

```
"less -R"
```

Comment: I made a pull request to fix the issue. I quickly set the PAGER variable to less and tried sdk list and it works! thanks for the help.

Comment: When configuring another system I realized `less` uses a separate `LESS` environment variable to read the options, so I think the sdkman.io project follows common practice to interpret `PAGER` variable as an executable only (and quotes were used to protect from non-alphanumeric characters in path).

Comment: So I ended up just setting PAGER=less and LESS=-R. nixos seems to require -R because man will not work properly without it.